# Why are my Alert.show windows *backwords*?

Tags: adobe, air

I'm writing an Adobe Air application, and for some reason, when I execute an Alert.show, the dialog box shows up backwards.  The text is backwords, the label on the button is backwards... and when I say backwards, I mean an exact mirror image, not just the word spelled with the letters in reverse order. If you looked at the dialog box in a mirror, then it would look perfect.

I'm doing it like this:
Alert.show("Help, I'm backwards!");

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Hopeless

Comment: It sounds like right-to-left text or rendering might be turned on somewhere. Are you using that in another part of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a problem that was created when I updated from Flex 4.0 to Flex 4.1.  You can find the solution here:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2985976

One less thing. :D